# how to set prefetch when using spring rabbitmq

Tags: spring, rabbitmq

If using spring with rabbitmq, how to set prefetch size to 1? The use case is to send task definition in xml to rabbitmq, and the many working servers could connect to it and do the task one by one. Since I'd like to have the max performance and let each server is busy, so I should set prefetch to 1 otherwise, some server could be much busier than the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` has the `setPrefetchCount` option, which is available from `rabbit` Namespace:

```
<rabbit:listener-container prefetch="1">
    <rabbit:listener queues="foo, bar" ref="myListener"/>
</rabbit:listener-container>
```